# Stopping tornado web server

Tags: python, process, tornado, inter-process-communicat

I know this question has already been asked, but the proposed solutions don't work for me. I'd like to run the tornado and would also like to be able to stop it somehow from another application's command.

The problem is, when following the solution in http://pastebin.com/KU3KN0Zh, how do I call the `stopTornado()` method if the process is already running (assuming the sleep and `stopTornado` at the end would be removed)?

I would essentially need another python script that could call this method (or send a message to the starttornado script).

Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use supervisor to run tornado and dig here http://supervisord.org/api.html However I don't understand why you can't call in `stopTornado` system command `supervisorctl -c <supervisor config> stop tornado:*`.

Comment: Thanks, but supervisor seems to rely on "UNIX-like operating systems" and I'm more after a portable solution that works on Windows, MacOS and Linux.

Comment: It must work on Mac also, because Mac is unix-like. For windows - use http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/ There are no portable solution at the moment.